# Scheduling a method to execute recursively and terminate that method

Tags: java

I have a method which will be called repeatedly after successive intervals.
I have used `public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)`.
How to stop this schedule method being called after certain time.

Right now i have no idea how to stop this method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could schedule the cancellation. For example, with a ScheduledExecutor, it could look like this:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    Runnable yourRecurrentTask = ...; //your recurrent task
    //run every seconds
    final ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.
            scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRecurrentTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Runnable cancelTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    };
    //cancel the reccurent task in 15 seconds
    scheduler.schedule(cancelTask, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just stop the timer after the given time? You can use another timer, which will fire only once and will stop the other timer.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule another task that hold a reference to your existing `TimerTask` and calls `cancel` on it. You should schedule this task as a one-time schedule with no repetition.